# Nginx chef docker

Tags: ruby, docker, nginx, containers, chef-infra

I am new to docker concept. For an application I need to create nginx container.
The nginx configuration is in chef cookbook, hence I have example.conf.erb file and default.rb (containing setup nginx file) in my chef/cookbook/ directory . I am not sure how to containerise. I copied .conf.erb to /etc/nginx/conf.d/example.conf.erb. I am not sure what else to do. I am confused and no resource online need help immediate
default.rb :

```
   include_recipe 'nginx_ldap_auth'
   include_recipe 'nginx'
   template 'nginx config' do
   source 'example.conf.erb'
   path '/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.conf.erb'

   owner 'root'
   group 'root'
   mode ''
   variables({'environment variables'})
   notifies :restart, 'service[nginx])'
```

My Dockerfile currently look like this:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/example.conf.erb/
```

I am not sure if I need docker-compose. Apart from Dockerfile there is nothing much I have created. Please guide

Comment: I think you are mixing up Chef and Docker. You should use Chef to generate the files (Dockerfile/example.conf.erb, etc) using `file` or `template` resource. Once you have such required files in a particular directory, Then the image can be built.

Comment: Should be `cookbook_file` resource instead of `file`.

Answer (score 0):

Either first let Chef create the config file and then run run docker build to create an image.

Or you can check out a *multi stage dockerfiles*.

With multiple stages you can first use an image that includes Chef, there create the config file and then copy it into the nginx image.